# how to clone specific calender control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have taken list view in asp x in that list view I have taken in layout template HTML table to show table header in item template I am finding all the controls i.e drop-down button and calendar control I have to create calendar control using jquery. I am doing functionality that when clicking on add row button so respective controls i.e drop down control and calendar should come in another row this all controls come except calendar control menace calendar control come but problem is that whenever you will click on it always clicked on the previous row itself menace what should I have to do please guide me I am going to share code with you

Comment: if you add some code, will probably help to get an answer

Comment: but sir where should i write code because whenever i writted my query it was not allowed me to post my code so i could not able to upload code please suggest me where should i post code Help me

Comment: Just write it down as text - find the way to place your code here - is not that difficult

Comment: i have posted question along with code please check give reply me if you got it.